# Music Player program freeze on Xbox

Tags: c, sdl, xbox, sdl-mixer

I am making a music player called XMusic, which you might know from another problem I have posted here. If you don't, I am making it for PC and Xbox (using nxdk), and it uses the SDL_mixer library. I have the problem where it doesn't open any file to play it, but that's a different problem. Since yesterday I am also encountering a problem where it just freezes after selecting a file (or even using a fixed one). Here is an example with both of the mentioned problems (from here and from my other question)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#if defined (NXDK)
#include <video.h>
#endif

static int audio_open = 0;
static Mix_Music *music = NULL;
char* fileToPlay = "D:\\Pause Test.wav";

static void PlayFile() {

int audio_rate = 48000; //48KHz saves Xbox CPU time
Uint16 audio_format = AUDIO_S16LSB;
int audio_channels = 2; 
int audio_buffers = 4096;
int audio_volume = MIX_MAX_VOLUME;
int looping = 1;

if (Mix_OpenAudio(audio_rate, audio_format, audio_channels, audio_buffers) < 0) {
  printf("Couldn't open audio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
} 
else {
  Mix_QuerySpec(&audio_rate, &audio_format, &audio_channels);
  printf("Opened audio at %d Hz %d bit%s %s %d bytes audio buffer\n", audio_rate,
  (audio_format&0xFF), (SDL_AUDIO_ISFLOAT(audio_format) ? " (float)" : ""),
  (audio_channels > 2) ? "surround" : (audio_channels > 1) ? "stereo" : "mono",
  audio_buffers);
}
audio_open = 1;

printf("Setting volume\n");
Mix_VolumeMusic(audio_volume);
printf("Opening %s\n", fileToPlay);

SDL_RWops *rw = SDL_RWFromFile(fileToPlay, "rb");

if (rw == NULL) {
    printf("Couldn't open %s: %s\n",
    fileToPlay, Mix_GetError());
}
printf("Loading %s\n", fileToPlay);
music = Mix_LoadMUS_RW(rw, SDL_TRUE);
if (music == NULL) {
    printf("Couldn't load %s: %s\n",
    fileToPlay, Mix_GetError());
}
printf("Loaded %s\n", fileToPlay);
Mix_FadeInMusic(music, looping, 2000);
 }


int main() {

#if defined (NXDK)
XVideoSetMode(640, 480, 32, REFRESH_DEFAULT);
#endif

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO|SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK);
Mix_Init(MIX_INIT_OGG|MIX_INIT_MP3);


PlayFile();

SDL_Delay(6000);

}
```

Running GDB on XMusic's debug build running on XQEMU (a low level emulator) shows me that it is stuck on 3 functions from SDL_mixer. Mix_HaltChannel(), Mix_QuerySpec(), and Mix_AllocateChannels(). It is like it is looping over all these 3.

XMusic's full code: https://github.com/kosmas12/My-code-stuff/tree/nxdk/Music%20player%20(C)

Comment: Sorry but your problem is too niche and chances to get an answer are very slim. Could you show full output of gdb, including backtrace? What `Mix_Init` returns? What's your program output (i.e. what do we have debug printfs actually print)? Does it work on pc? Are you sure your sdl mixer build is not faulty and actually can play any sound? What versions of SDL and SDL_mixer?

Comment: How can I see what Mix_Init returns? Program output is absolutely nothing, maybe because it crashes early on before actually printing, on the 3 mentioned functions. It works fine on PC, the build is not faulty as its sample works, SDL and SDL_mixer are 2.0.9. I will report back with GDB output when I am on my PC. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: Well `Mix_Init` returns an int, which you can assign into a variable (it should return the same parameters you passed into it if init is successful). If you can attach gdb to your program - you can break on main function and step it through, inspecting program flow and values of variables.

Comment: I set logging on etc. but it didn't capture any of the GDB output lines where it says where it has stopped in the log file, though it is looping over Mix_QuerySpec(), Mix_HaltChannel() and Mix_AllocateChannels(), just as when I first tried debugging it. For some reason it doesn't print anything about the variable I gave it for Mix_Init(), it just says that it doesn't exist, but I've made sure I had recompiled (make said there was nothing to do), and also made sure that I stopped execution in a point after the variable was given a value.

Comment: If you have optimisation on, compiler is free to remove your variables ("value optimised out"). If you use gcc, for debugging you want to use `-O0 -g3` flags (I don't know what toolchain is used for xbox). Older versions of SDL used to redirect stdout on some platforms, is there `stdout.txt` file?

Comment: There is no stdout.txt, it doesn't generate one, and nxdk uses clang. I will look up the flags and report back in a bit. Thank you!

Comment: So, I checked the return values of Mix_Init, and it returns the flags that we give it. So I went ahead and made a variable that calls Mix_Init() with another variable containing flags, and then on an if statement I compared the values of the Mix_Init() variable with the flags variable, like the docs also do, and if they are not the same it should error. And it does error, but Mix_GetError() returns nothing, which means that there is no error and my logic is bad or SDL_mixer just doesn't report an error.

Comment: Turns out it is because of the port's limited support for audio formats, just initializing OGG works...

Comment: No, `SDL_GetError` is to provide text description of an error, not to indicate there was an error. https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError says "You must check the return values of SDL function calls to determine when to appropriately call SDL_GetError()", and it is indeed happens that error description is returned but there was no reason for checking it. And Mix_GetError is just a macro that calls SDL_GetError, so same rules apply here.

Comment: So, I got the return value of it on both PC and Xbox, with only the OGG init flag it returns 16 on both PC and Xbox, with all flags it returns 123 on PC and 16 on Xbox, maybe because the port currently only supports .wav and .ogg files. So it is probably fine in init.